# How to create conditional plots of groupby objects using matplotlib/seaborn?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have data from a University where each entry is a student with the columns (first name, last name, major, sex, etc.)

I have created an aggregation of counts of male and females in each major:

```
gender_counts = (only_science.groupby(['no_concentration', 'sex'], as_index=False)
         .size()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .sort_values('Female', ascending=False)
        )
```

Output:
[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6zBD.png)

Here is the plot that I created:

```
ax3 = gender_counts.plot(kind='bar', title='Gender Breakdown by Major')
ax3.set_xlabel("CoS Majors")
ax3.set_ylabel("Number of Applicants")
plt.show()
```

Output: [Majors Plot by Gender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7COBd.png)

Goal: Create individual graphs of each major using the aggregated data so that the scale can be more meaningful and not be skewed by Biological Sciences.

I have tried to use `sns.FacetGrid()` and `FacetGrid.map()` and also tried `sns.catplot()` but I'm not sure what use for the parameters, and get a plethora of errors.

If I can create a bar chart for one of the majors then I can just create a for loop to iterate over gender_counts and make all of the bar charts.

Thank you for your help and I apologize if there are elements missing from this question. This is my first stack overflow question.

Comment: Hi Daniel, see my answer. In future use `df.to_dict()` and paste within `DataFrame()` as I have done, so that your data can easily be run. Also, kindly accept as solution by clicking the checkmark next to my answer, or let me know if you are looking for some thing different and what that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sns.catplot` with `sharey=False`:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'no_concentration': {0: 'Biological Sciences',1: 'Pre-Medicine',2: 'Biochemistry',3: 'Pre-Dentistry',4: 'Chemistry',
  5: 'Mathematics',6: 'Physics',7: 'Microbiology',8: 'Geology',9: 'Biological Sciences',10: 'Pre-Medicine',
  11: 'Biochemistry',12: 'Pre-Dentistry',13: 'Chemistry',14: 'Mathematics',15: 'Physics',16: 'Microbiology',17: 'Geology'},
 'Sex': {0: 'Female',1: 'Female',2: 'Female',3: 'Female',4: 'Female',5: 'Female',6: 'Female',7: 'Female',8: 'Female',9: 'Male',10: 
         'Male',11: 'Male',12: 'Male',13: 'Male',14: 'Male',15: 'Male', 16: 'Male',17: 'Male'},
 'value': {0: 1282,1: 1267, 2: 291, 3: 187, 4: 175, 5: 89, 6: 75, 7: 57,8: 18,9: 534,10: 445,11: 122,12: 76,13: 80,14: 76,15: 118,16: 29,17: 31}})
sns.set_context('paper', font_scale=1.4)
sns.catplot(data=df, x='Sex', y='value', col='no_concentration', kind='bar', 
                 col_wrap=3, palette=sns.color_palette("icefire"), sharey=False)
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
plt.style.use('dark_background') #I use dark mode in jupyter notebook, so I need to use this line, but you can omit.
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Also thanks for the tip on making my questions more useful!